# form session data not posting, sessions working

Tags: php, forms, session, submit

I've been tinkering with this for a few days. Checked out all the posts related and still can't quite get it to work. Anyone able to take a look and steer me in the right direction?

I have a site where everything gets loaded into a div on a page.
everything is working great except the form data.
I can load the session data for a test and it works fine, however i can't seem to get any of the entered form data.

i have the session_start(); included at the top just under the opening php tag in connection.php. connection.php is required on each page.

connection.php beginning.

```
<?
 session_start();
```

Here are some code samples from addvehicle.php (not posting it all as it's huge and the rest is not relevant, can if need be though)

...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
            $('form#newvehicleform').submit(function()
            {
            <?php
            $trucknumbera=$_POST["trucknumber"];
            $_SESSION['trucknumber']=$trucknumbera;
            $_SESSION['info']="this is some info";
            ?>
                    $("#mainwindow").load("addvehiclepost.php");
                    return false;
            });
    });
</script>
```

.....

```
  <form id="newvehicleform" class="newvehicleform" method="post" action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF;?>">
  <table>
  <tr>
       <td>
            Truck Number
       </td>
        <td>
                <input name="trucknumber" class="validate[required,custom[number]]" type="text" id="trucknumber" autofocus autocomplete="off" required />
          </td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
            <br>
            <input type="submit" id="submit" class="s-submit" alt="Submit" value="Submit">
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

the test of, addvehiclepost.php

```
require ('./connection.php');
echo "<br>info: " .$_SESSION['info']. "<br>";
$trucknumber=$_SESSION['trucknumber'];
echo "<br>trucknumber: " .$trucknumber;
```

and here is the output i get from addvehiclepost.php

> info: this is some info
>
> trucknummer:

so you can see it's passing the $_SESSION properly and that function is working however I just can't get it to pass the submitted for data.

Anyone have any ideas on getting this to go?

Thanks in advance.
-Colin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you execute your first script with PHP, there is no form data.

And the PHP fragment executed there does not do anything besides transfering an empty POST value (NULL) to a local variable and then to the session array.

I think you think that this PHP code gets executed when the javascript is called, but this is not the case! First all PHP is executed, and the result is echoed back to the browser. Then the page is rendered and javascript is executed.

So the PHP part of your code does copy an empty value (and sets a static one as well, that's what you see) at the time the form page is first loaded by the browser.

Then javascript acts. Which would mean in your case that there is no form POST request, but simply a GET request for the `addvehiclepost.php` script. No POST request means no `$_POST` data. Which isn't accessed in the loaded script anyway.

I don't know if you are able to fix this, but I hope I enabled you to understand the structural error of your code. I have seen this with about any newbie I know.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense now that I see it that way.
I haven't been able to find a work around just yet.

Any suggestions on getting it to pass the values of the form through?